# React Native Stripe SDK: How to give focus to cardNumber input in CardField component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm using the new react native sdk for Stripe which is pretty neat, I want to  give focus to cardfield component when user clicks on button or programatically, is it currently possible?

https://github.com/stripe/stripe-react-native

I find autofocus property in the docs but that's not exactly what I need

```
<CardField
               autofocus={true}
        postalCodeEnabled={false}
        placeholder={{
          number: '4242 4242 4242 4242',
        }}
        cardStyle={{
          backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
          textColor: '#000000',
        }}
        style={{
          width: '100%',
          height: 50,
          marginVertical: 30,
          padding:0
        }}
        onCardChange={(cardDetails) => {
          console.log('cardDetails', cardDetails);
          updateCardDetails(cardDetails);
        }}
        onFocus={(focusedField) => {
          console.log('focusField', focusedField);
        }}
      />
```

Answer (score 0):

How about adding `isCardFocused` prop dynamically, if certain flag variable is on?
And changing the value of that variable when as needed.

```
<CardField
  ...(isCardFocused && { autofocus: true })
  postalCodeEnabled={false}
```